# How to make spring security permit access to static resources?

Tags: css, spring, spring-security, static, resources

I decided to add some css to my application but it isn't working because of spring security. Here is what i tried to fix this.
1)adding to the mvcConfig

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}
```

2)added this to webSecurityConfig

```
 @Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
            .ignoring()
            .antMatchers("/resources/**");
}
```

3)also i have this method

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/","/registration","/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

4. also i added this to application.properties file:
   `spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**`

none of this methods are working for me. if anyone dealt with this, please help

you can check out the whole project if it helps [my project](https://github.com/sanchopansa8/Organizel)

p.s. i'm just a beginner in spring, so dont judge me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to ignore the css directory too.

```java
@Component
public class SecurityConfig implements WebSecurityConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web
            .ignoring() 
                .antMatchers("/css/**")
                .antMatchers("/js/**")
                .antMatchers("/images/**")
                .antMatchers("/resources/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: Place the css files in the path `/main/webapp/css`.